# How to reuse fiedls in graphql queries

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, react-apollo

I know how to use fragments, my problem right now is that fragments can only be used within queries/mutations for a type.

Eg.

```
paginationFragment on Person
```

I guess what I am looking for is similar to fragments but more general.

Eg. I have a PersonBrowseQuery, EventsBrowseQuery, BookmarkBrowseQuery etc. All have a meta field containing my pagination data

```
meta {
  total
  per_page
  current_page  

  etc.    
}
```

Is it possible to factor this to a reusable thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your meta field is a type, so you can still use a fragment for it:

```
const metaFragment = gql`
  fragment MetaFields on MetaType {
    total
    per_page
    current_page  
    # other fields    
  }`
```

It can then be included in your queries as a using template literal place holder syntax:

```
const usersQuery = gql`
  query getUsers {
    users {
      meta {
        ...MetaFields
      }
      # other fields
    }
  }
  ${metaFragment}
}`
```

Just make sure the name of the fragment (`MetaFields` in this example) matches. **Alternatively,** if you have some shared fields that aren't necessarily a fragment and you're bent on staying as DRY as possible, you can just use a plain template literal:

```
const sharedFields = `
  bar
  baz
  qux
`
const usersQuery = gql`
  query getFoo {
    foo {
      ${sharedFields}
      # other fields
    }
  }
}`
```

Comment: For the second option, I got this error: `String interpolation is not allowed in graphql tag:`